# How to use Zend Log as a separated component?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-log

I want to use Zend Framwork's Log mechanism as a separated component,that means all I want from ZF is just the Log, How can I do this?

Comment: All I mean is how to initialize Zend Log feature

Comment: The [Zend_Log_Writer manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.log.writers.html) seems pretty straightforward. Are you asking for something more than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to these two pages

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.5/en/requirements.zendcomponents.html
- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/requirements.dependencies.html

`Zend_Log` requires `Zend_Exception` and the following

- DOM
- libxml
- Reflection

What this means is that you really only need the following from the framework itself

```
library/Zend/Exception.php
library/Zend/Log.php
library/Zend/Log <- the directory
```

You should then be able to use the logger as a stand-alone component. Just add the `library` folder in the list above to your include path (Zend Framework components rely on this)

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/path/to/library',
    get_include_path()
)));

require_once 'Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php';
require_once 'Zend/Log.php';

$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/path/to/logfile');
$log = new Zend_Log($writer);
$log->log('Some message', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to use individual components from Zend Framework I simply include a small file called `zend_setup.php` that contains the following three lines of code:

```
set_include_path( '/Users/me/workspace/proj_name/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once( '/Users/me/workspace/proj_name/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' );
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

This is probably not as efficient as issuing explicit `require_once()` statements, but I like the convenience it offers. For example, you may very quickly decide you also want to utilize `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug()` and `Zend_Log_Writer_Mail()`. Using the autoloader avoids having to write all those additional `require_once()` statements.